# MariaDb Replication

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replication

I was trying to replicate between master server and slave server, but master server are private ip and having different location with slave server. Any suggestion?

Comment: use a VPN Connection

Comment: I think you can white-list slave IP on master, It will allow you to communicate from master to slave.

Comment: @BerndBuffen any recommend vpn and how to set up ?

Comment: @Kelvin Tan - you can install OpenVPN on both Systems. There are many tutorials to do that. After the installation you can reach both system via an internal IP, as if they were in the same Network.